# ACPI Bios Error while installing Ubuntu 18.04 on NUC-11PHKi7C

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, bios, intel-nuc

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on NUC-11PHKi7C from a bootable drive but I receive the following error and the system freezes:[image]

Is there a work around to solve this problem. I have seen that installing Ubuntu 20.04 on the NUC is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Why don't you try 20.04 then?

Comment: I have dependencies for a sensor driver which is not released in 20.04 yet. So, I am forced to use 18.04

Comment: A release from 3 years before the hardware is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

What I found works is a modification of Chenxi Yang's answer above.  The sequence of events in those instructions was incomplete and some steps were unnecessary.  However, I thank Chenxi Yang for the step of editing the grub startup by pressing e in grub and adding `nomodeset`.  That is the key.  What worked for me for Ubuntu 18.04 was:

1. When booting from Ubuntu 18.04 install media from either the first or second item in the grub list, press <kbd>e</kbd>.
2. Replace the `---` after splash with `nomodeset`, and push <kbd>F10</kbd>.  As the previous answer states, this will bypass the ACPI error, which seems to be with the Intel graphics and not NVIDIA.
3. Let the system startup.  Run the `Install Ubuntu 18.04...`.
4. After installation, remove the install media and allow the system to restart.  However, you need to boot into the grub menu.  If it is not setup to go into grub automatically, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during initial bootup to go into the grub menu.
5. In the grub menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> on the top choice (boot Ubuntu normally).
6. Edit the line that starts with "linux" and change the end of the line where it says `splash $vt_handoff` to `splash nomodeset` (no quotes).  Hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting.
7. Once into Ubuntu, edit `/etc/default/grub`  (e.g `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`)
8. Find the line that says:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

9. Save the file and close it.
10. In a terminal, run:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Reboot.  Then you should be able to boot correctly and you can install the NVIDIA drivers if you want.  You can also choose the drivers from the Software & Updates App

Answer (score -1):

Since several other problems will occur concerning the NVIDIA driver after you solve this ACPI error (took me two days to find the way out), I will provide my complete solution.

1. Instead of installing Ubuntu, select try Unbuntu without installing, and push E.
2. Replace the "---" after splash with "nomodeset", and push F10. This step will solve the ACPI error.
3. Download the drivers in the following link: https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/179599/en-us
   Install the .run file (before the installation, you need to install gcc first)
4. Do NOT restart the computer as recommended, otherwise, you will get a black screen and have to start from the first step again. Push the install Ubuntu 18.04 icon and start installing the OS to your Nuc. Remember to select installing the 3rd-party software.

I wish it works for you.